# Throwing out same response on login check PHP AND SWIFT

Tags: php, json, swift

I am trying to try and learn swift but want a backend server for php and need to convert the php to json to the app

Now what I want is to put email and password in the fields on app and it send a post request to the php server side and the php validates the details and sends back the response which will let me then decide what to do with the response.

I have managed to post to the server side with success I think but when I get the response back in the xcode it gives the same output weather the details are correct or in-correct,I have looked every where and followed tutorials but I keep getting the same problem I'm guessing its the way I am check details in the php file as I always get the error and not success.

Could someone help?

login.php

```
$email = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
$password = addslashes(strip_tags($_POST['password']));
$password = md5($password);
$returnValue = array();

$sql = "SELECT email, user_password FROM `Accounts` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND user_password = '$password' LIMIT 1";
$fetchuser = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql);
$row = mysqli_num_rows($fetchuser);

if($row = mysqli_num_rows($fetchuser) == 0){
  $returnValue["status"] = "error";
  $returnValue["message"] = "Account not found";
  echo json_encode($returnValue);
} else {
  $returnValue["status"] = "success";
  $returnValue["message"] = "Account found";
  echo json_encode($returnValue);
}
```

Swift Code

```
    let userEmail = UserEmailTextField.text;
    let userPassword = UserPasswordTextField.text;

    if(userEmail!.isEmpty || userPassword!.isEmpty)  { return; }

    //SEND TO SERVER
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://chaozsounds.com/chaozsounds/New-ChaozSounds/TeamChaozApp/register.php")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "email=\(userEmail)&password=\(userPassword)"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else {                                                          // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response!)")
        }

        let returnValue = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("returnValue = \(returnValue!)")
        if(returnValue == "success") {

            // LOGIN SUCCESSFUL
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey:"isUserLoggedIn");
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so had to work around and I managed to do what I was after so will put code below

```
// Send post request

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "urllinkhere")!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";
    let postString = "email=\(userEmail!)&password=\(userPassword!)";
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

    // Get success or error

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        if error != nil {
            print("no data found: \(error)")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response!)")
        }

        // this, on the other hand, can quite easily fail if there's a server error, so you definitely
        // want to wrap this in `do`-`try`-`catch`:

        do {
            let json =  try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            if let parseJSON = json {
                let returnValue = parseJSON["status"] as? String;

                print("returnValue = \(returnValue!)")

                if(returnValue == "success") {

                    // SUCCESS
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true,forKey:"isUserLoggedIn");
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();

                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);

                }


            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```